# How to make shell script run by double-click?

Tags: ssh

I have a script which is executable from command line but I want to make it user friendly as I want to run this script by double clicking on it. How it is possible?

```
#! /bin/bash

cd

cd Desktop/D_usman/

java -jar imageSynch.jar
```

Comment: This depends on which desktop environment you are using, i.e. whether you are on a Mac, or using KDE, Gnome, Unity etc.

Comment: Beside from Michael's very important question (question is impossible to answer without that information), what it have to do with 'ssh' tag?

Comment: Soory, I am using ubuntu12.04 gnome-classic enviroment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add ".command" to the end of the name of your shellscript on Mac OS X.

Comment: but I am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Ok. There seems to be a space on the first line. There should not be any.

Comment: well I have removed it but it is still same

Comment: Try adding a space and then "-xv" at the end of the first line and running it again from the commandline. Say what you see.

Comment: Thank you but I want to run it by double clicking on the file not from command line.

Comment: I understand that, but I want to be sure it runs correctly from the commandline first before worrying about a problem with double-clicking that may not exist.

Comment: If you are using Nautilus, press Alt + F10 and select Preferences. Change setting about how to deal with scripts, i.e. open versus execute.

Comment: There is nothing happen after pressing Alt+F10 for your information the environment is gnome-classic (no effect).

Comment: Thanks for your support but I found a way that is I replace the line "java -jar imageSynch.jar" with "/usr/lib/jvm/bin/java -jar imageSynch.jar" & the script runs by double clicking. & I found this path by using command "which java".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add execute permissions for the user, group, or rest of the world, depending on who should be allowed to execute it. Look into `chmod` for more information.

Example: `chmod u+x myscript`

Once you do this, you can also start the shell script like this `./myscript` instead of `sh myscript.sh`

Note: You can also make your JAR start by adding execute permission, given Java is setup correctly on your machine.

Comment: Thank you but the permissions are already set for this script & I want to execute it by double clicking on the file not from command line as you said.

Comment: Maybe nautilus isn't setup to execute it. The second answer here worked for me, not sure if it works for gnome classic though: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-bash-scripts-in-nautilus